# How to find 3 dB bandwidth of any transfer function?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

Suppose we have a transfer function

$$
G(s) =\frac{2(s+3)}{(s+6)(s+1)}
$$
I want to know how to find out the \$3\textrm{ dB}\$ bandwidth of this transfer function?

Comment: I am afraid, there is no other chance than to apply the definition based on the magnitude of this complex function.

Answer (score 6):

the *"3 dB bandwidth"* is more precisely called the *"-3.01 dB bandwidth"* and even more precisely called the "**half-power bandedge**".

so begin with your transfer function

$$ H(s) = \frac{b_0 + b_1s + b_2s^2 + ... + b_N s^N}{a_0 + a_1s + a_2s^2 + ... + a_N s^N} \triangleq \frac{P(s)}{Q(s)} $$

evaluate this at an arbitrary frequency \$\omega\$ on the imaginary axis on the \$s\$-plane.

$$ H(j\omega) = \frac{P(j\omega)}{Q(j\omega)} $$

that represents voltage gain (and phase shift) frequency response.  for power gain, it's the magnitude-squared of the frequency response:

$$ |H(j\omega)|^2 = \left| \frac{P(j\omega)}{Q(j\omega)} \right|^2 $$

evaluate the magnitude squared at the "**center**" of your passband.  let's say it's a low-pass filter (LPF) as is the example in the question above.  the center of the passband (when you also include negative \$\omega\$) is at DC or \$\omega=0\$

$$ |H(j0)|^2 = \left| \frac{P(0)}{Q(0)} \right|^2 $$

the -3 dB frequency is at the frequency which results in half of the power as in the center of the passband (in this case, at DC).

$$ |H(j\omega)|^2 = \frac12 |H(0)|^2 $$

or

$$ \left| \frac{P(j\omega)}{Q(j\omega)} \right|^2 = \frac12 \ \left| \frac{P(0)}{Q(0)} \right|^2 $$

or

$$ 2 \ |Q(0) \ P(j\omega)|^2 = |P(0) \ Q(j\omega)|^2 $$

solve for \$\omega\$ and you have your -3 dB bandwidth.

Comment: "bandedge" - that's a new one for me!

Comment: @Andyaka, for a BPF or a notch-like response, "bandwidth" is the width of the band or the distance between the two bandedges.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got your hint. But I was looking for a technique by which it can be solved easily. As the function complication increases, it would be quite difficult to solve the equation for 'w'. That's why I asked the question. Anyways thanks again.

Comment: it's not a hint.  it is the essentially the only procedure for *"how to find [the] -3 dB bandwidth for any [rational] transfer function"*. your example was for a 2nd order transfer function.  that \$\omega\$ can be solved directly and exactly.  (actually you would first solve for \$\omega^2\$.)  even though there are exact solutions for arbitrary 3rd and maybe 4th order, of course for order higher than 2nd, you would likely use a numerical method, probably Newton-Rahpson or the secant method, to solve the higher-order polynomial of \$\omega^2\$.  then. of course, square root that result.

Answer (score 1):

A ballpark value can be obtained by looking at the magnitude plot.

[image]

Or it can be explicitly solved with a symbolic system like Mathematica.

[image]

Comment: ... or with pen and paper, like in the good olden days :)

Comment: true, but I'm no longer in those days... :)

Comment: "w" is not "\$\omega\$".  unless you're forced to do "ASCII math" like at newsgroup *comp.dsp*.

Comment: You don't like me using 'w' for frequency. Is that it, or am I missing something more?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer seems perfect. But I was looking for a technique by which it can be solved either intuitively or with pen and paper easily. But as the function complication increases, it would be quite difficult to solve it using your method. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB you can simply enter the transfer function in the form of the coefficients of the numerator and denominator polynomials:

>>mytf = tf([2 6],[1 7 6])

>> bandwidth(mytf)

ans =

```
1.0890
```

---

Or if you want (say) the -20dB bandwidth:

>>bandwidth(mytf, -20)

ans =

19.3018

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way. Convert your transfer function in standard form (evidencing the frequencies):

$$H(s) = \frac{2(s+3)}{(s+6)(s+1)} = \frac{\frac{s}{3}+1}{(\frac{s}{6}+1)(s+1)}$$

As the real poles are sufficiently separated, in other words, 1–2 octaves in the worst case, the 3-dB frequency can be estimated (response dominated by) as the the lowest frequency pole (**1 rad/s**):

$$H(s) \simeq \frac{1}{s+1}$$

Dominant pole: One of the poles is of much lower/higher frequency than any of the other poles and zeros (the lowest/highest frequency pole is at least two octaves away from the nearest pole or zero). My response refers to the HIGH FREQUENCY estimation for transfer function response, when there is a dominant (lower) frequency pole. However, a zero near the origin lead to a differentiation effect (contributing to the shape of magnitude plot in low frequencies). In this case if there is a dominant (higher) frequency pole, it will dictate the curve shape (-3dB) at the LOW FREQUENCY. Anyway, for a more accurate estimation, see the extensive literature for sketching Bode plot diagrams.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. From your answer I suppose that it is the first frequency at which the - 20db/decade fall occurs in the bode plot. Did I get it right? If yes, is it applicable for more complicated functions having more than one zeroes and poles? And what if the zero occurs before the first pole? It would be great if u can elaborate with such an example.